# I need to double click on the "Login" button to display the Email and Password in console.log using Ionic + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, capacitor

on my case I need to double click on the "Login" button to display the Email and Password

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { IonButton, IonCardContent, IonContent, IonIcon, IonInput, IonItem, IonList, IonLoading, IonPage, useIonRouter } from '@ionic/react';
import { mailOpenOutline, lockClosedOutline } from 'ionicons/icons';

const LoginPage: React.FC = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const navigation = useIonRouter();

  useEffect(() => {}, [email, password])

  const handlerLogin = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("set", email, "this email");
    console.log("set", password, "this password");
  }

  const signUp = () => {
    navigation.push('/register')
  }

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent className="ion-padding">
        <IonCardContent>
          <IonList>
            <form onSubmit={handlerLogin}>
              <IonItem>
                <IonInput
                  label='Email'
                  labelPlacement='stacked'
                  placeholder='example@email.com'
                  type='email'
                  clearInput={true}
                  onIonChange={(e: any) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                >
                  <IonIcon slot='start' icon={mailOpenOutline} />
                </IonInput>
              </IonItem>
              <IonItem>
                <IonInput
                  className='ion-margin-top'
                  label='Password'
                  labelPlacement='stacked'
                  placeholder='*******'
                  type='password'
                  onIonChange={(e:any) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                >
                  <IonIcon slot='start' icon={lockClosedOutline} />
                </IonInput>
              </IonItem>
              <IonButton type='submit' expand='full' shape='round' fill='outline'>
                Login
              </IonButton>
            </form>
            <IonButton color={'danger'} expand='full' shape='round' fill='outline' onClick={() => signUp()}>
              Daftar
            </IonButton>
            <IonLoading isOpen={loading} message={'Harap Tunggu'} />
          </IonList>
        </IonCardContent>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

when I click once on the "Login" button on the console.log it displays an image like this
[image]

and when I double click the "Login" button it will display console.log like this
[image]

- clone repo
- https://github.com/ujangaripin24/ionic-react-firebase-chating make
- sure you using Node 20.xx.x make sure you using Ionic 7.x.x Ionic cap
- run android -l --livereload --external wait util Project running on
- SDK open inspect element with chrome using 'chrome://inspect' on
- Adress Bar enter Email and Password and click once on the button and
- click the button again a second time

I want to display the Email and Password on the console.log with just one click of the "Login" button, how do I do it? is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Not Ionic related but a general js question. But the idea would be to use a boolean flag to keep track of whether the button has been clicked twice:

```
const [clickCount, setClickCount] = useState(0);

const handleDoubleClick = () => {
setClickCount(clickCount + 1);

if (clickCount === 2) {
  console.log('Double click action');
  setClickCount(0); // Reset the count
}
```

};